# Running tomcat7 maven plugin with custom classpath using VirtualWebappLoader

Tags: tomcat7, maven-3, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a maven *war* project, that I'm trying to run with tomcat7-maven-plugin. The problem I'm having is that the configuration for each of the environments is in custom folder (it's not inside /resources), as we have a different set of configuration files for each environments (local, test, uat or production).

I'm trying to figure out how can I run the plugin, while specifying a custom classpath that includes the **local** configuration directory. I've read on this [improvement ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-189) that the way to do it, is to provide a context.xml with a `Loader` element, but if I do this, the webapp fails to start.

The configuration I have in the pom is

```xml
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
           <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
           <contextFile>${basedir}/src/env/local/context.xml</contextFile>
           <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

the context.xml file (the tomcat plugin does the filtering on this file automatically)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
   <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" 
           virtualClasspath="${basedir}/src/env/local/" />

   <JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true" />
</Context>
```

And the error I get is

```
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /webapp
Handler error
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.FileHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:521)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:464)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager$2.run(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:377)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager$2.run(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:373)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.getClassLoaderInfo(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:373)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:452)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager$2.run(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:377)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager$2.run(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:373)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.getClassLoaderInfo(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:373)
        at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.getLogger(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:223)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:389)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:288)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:170)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.getLogger(ContainerBase.java:452)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion about how to fix this or achieve the same in a different way?

I've been able to do this with the cargo plugin, but the tomcat plugin has some features that I like :).

Comment: Hi Augusto, I too am using Tomcat 7 for my Maven Java EE project. I want to configure VirtualWebappLoader to look in a certain dir for .jars. This directory is "/Library/Tomcat/mydir". I have tried several configurations as virtualClasspath, but I can't get it to work. Can you help? Thx!!

Comment: I haven't been able to make it work neither :S. In the end I decided to copy the configuration files manually to a folder that tomcat can see inside the project. It's not ideal, but that allows me to start  tomcat (and test any changes) very quickly.

Comment: Aw, that's too bad. Thanks for your comment and good you found a work-around! :)

Comment: I'm confused as to why you cannot use the `additionalClasspathDirs` option to the Maven Tomcat Plugin? That seems to have worked for me before, to provide additional `.properties` files that I wanted to be picked up.

Comment: Hi Sander! It just didn't work :(. If you could provide an answer with a minimal example, I could try it. (at the same time, it could be that this was fixed in a later tomcat7-maven-plugin version, a now they are on v2.2)